# Why doesn't this C code print a negative integer?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C. I use the book "C programming - A Modern Approach". 
I did an excercise in this book. But I don't understand WHY this code doesn't print a negative number when I fill in a negative number. 
Maybe I missed a little detail or it's just something stupid, so please help me. 
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    printf("Vul een negatief getal in: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    printf("%d\n", i >= 0 ? i : -i);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printf("%d\n", i >= 0 ? i : -i);`

- If you inputed a positive number (or zero), e.g. `5` it will print `i` i.e. `5`
- If you inputed a negative number, e.g. `-5` it will print `-i` i.e. `-(-5)` which is `5`

---

If case you are unfamiliar with the ternary operator here is how it works:

```
CONDITION ? EXPR_TRUE : EXPR_FALSE
```

it tests the `CONDITION` and if `true` it evaluates EXPR_TRUE, else it evaluates `EXPR_FALSE`

In your case:

```
i >= 0 ? i : -i
```

yields `i` if `i >= 0` or `-i` otherwise.

Comment: Aaaah I didn't think about those parentheses around the five! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) here,

```
printf("%d\n", i >= 0 ? i : -i);
```

The ternary takes the absolute value. It can be expanded to

```
if (i >= 0) {
  printf("%d\n", i);
} else {
  printf("%d\n", -i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of `i >= 0 ? i : -i`

if i >= 0, for example i = 3, then print 3

if i < 0, for example i = -3, then print -(-3) = 3

So although i is -ve sometimes but print output is never -ve for you.